# asp.net gridview dynamically binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, paging, page-index-changed

i have a GridView,

```
<asp:GridView ID="managerList" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
```

in the code behind,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "select * from manager";
    managerList.AllowPaging = true;
}
```

when i load the page, it works fine, the paging works fine, too.

Then i want to get the subset of the list by click on a search button:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "select * from manager where age > 30";
    managerList.DataBind();
}
```

it works fine, give me the subset of the list.

However, when i click on "next page", it gives me the whole list, page #2. I know it's because it sends a postback, and it bind the original select command. But how can i do to give me the subset of the list when i click on "next page"?

Thank you!

**UPDATES:**
if i change the code into this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!IsPostBack)
  {
    SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "select * from manager";
    managerList.AllowPaging = true;
  }
}
```

it gives me an empty list when i click on "next page".

it might be tempted to add IsPostBack, but this not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the NewPageIndex code in the PageIndexChanging event:

```
managerList.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
bindgrid();
```

Answer (score 1):

Below might help you

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
    SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "select * from manager";
    managerList.AllowPaging = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: no it won't. when i click on "next page", it gives me an empty list.

Comment: protected void managerList_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
managerList.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
bindgrid();
}

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your code under `!IsPostBack()` in the page_load event. like...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!IsPostBack)
  {
    SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "select * from manager";
    managerList.AllowPaging = true;
  }
}
```

**Reason:** Whenever you hit the Next button, your page load event is called before the `PageIndexChanging` Event handler of Gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Page_Load fires every time the page is loaded, including postbacks, so your select statement is getting reset. Try setting a viewstate value to keep your select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Store the most recent SQL Query in a global static string and then use the following code.

```
static String previousSQL_Query;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(IsPostBack)
  {
    SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = previousSQL_Query;
  }
  else
  {
       SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "select * from manager";
       managerList.AllowPaging = true;
  }
}

protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "select * from manager where age > 30";
    previousSQL_Query = SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand;
    managerList.DataBind();
}
```